# AutoCompleteTextView develop a arraylist and choose name

Tags: java, android, list, listview, autocompletetextview

In my application, I won't use AutoCompleteTextView to complete the word from the array list.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_initial_cost );

    String[] tipsNameCost=getResources().getStringArray( R.array.name_costs );

    editTextCostName=(AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById( R.id.edit_text_initial_cost_name );

    ArrayAdapter<String> editTextAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,tipsNameCost);
    AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_initial_cost_name);
    textView.setThreshold(0);
    textView.setAdapter(editTextAdapter);
```

XML

```
 <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_initial_cost_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:editable="true"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:ems="10">

        <requestFocus/>
    </AutoCompleteTextView>
```

It's work when I click in editTextCostName and I will write the first letter of the word. But I won't do When the user clicks on the editextCostName field, a list with hints to choose from must be displayed immediately. So that he could choose a word from the list. How to do it?

Comment: Might want to look into this example: https://github.com/farizdotid/AutoCompleteTextview-Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

You can simple use `showDropDown()` like this:

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View arg0) {
        textView.setMaxLines(5);
        textView.showDropDown();

    }
});
```

That's it, Hope it works.